# Open-source fonts visually similar to FF Fago or Neo Sans Intel

Tags: font-recommendation

Are there open-source fonts visually similar to [FF Fago](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/fontfont/ff-fago/) or Neo Sans Intel (used on intel.com website and also Intel manuals ([small example](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/architecture-and-technology/64-architecture-x2apic-specification.html)))?

Answer (score 0):

From a quick visual check:

- FF Fago: [Adobe Source Sans Pro](http://store1.adobe.com/cfusion/store/html/index.cfm?event=displayFontPackage&code=1959)
- Neo Sans Intel: [Latin Modern Sans](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/lmodernsans/)

Note that I didn't do a detailed comparison (didn't check letter spacing in particular); those are just what comes to my mind and seem relatively similar. If you are looking for specific font features / characteristics, please specify them.

Answer (score 0):

I would use "Ubuntu" to replace the "NeoSans".

To replace "Fago" I would use "Aller".

They’re both designed by The Dalton Maag Font Foundrie.

The first one, "Ubuntu", is free to use and you can download it from  http://www.google.com/fonts/.

The second one is free, but only up to 25 users, and you can download it here: http://www.daltonmaag.com/buyonline/sans/aller.